# Comma Separated Value in Select Clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have two tables: CONFIRMATION & CONFIRMATION_PRESS

**CONFORMATION** Table looks like following:

```
ID_CONF   |  ID_LOT |  QTY
1005         175       25
1006         175       24
1007         175       23
1008         176       50
```

**CONFIRMATION_PRESS** Table looks like following:

```
ID_CONF |  ID_PRESS
1005       11
1005       22
1005       33
1006       12
1006       13
1007       14
```

Now I want all the data for ID_LOT = 175 from CONFIRMATION Table but I need ID_PRESS in comma separated value.

For example, for ID_LOT 175, the following results should be displayed:

```
ID CONF | ID_LOT | QTY | ID_PRESS
--------+--------+-----+----------
1005      175      25    11,22,33
1006      175      24     12,13
1007      175      23     14
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT
    C.ID_CONF,
    C.QTY,
    C.ID_LOT,
    STUFF((  
      SELECT CAST(',' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(CP.ID_PRESS AS VARCHAR(5))
      FROM CONFIRMATION C,
           CONFIRMATION_PRESS CP
      WHERE
          C.ID_CONF = CP.ID_CONF
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') PRESS_CSV
FROM
    CONFIRMATION C 
WHERE 
    C.ID_LOT = 175
```

But it returns this output:

```
 ID CONF | ID_LOT | QTY | ID_PRESS
 --------+--------+-----+------------------
 1005       175      25    11,22,33,12,13
 1006       175      24    11,22,33,12,13
 1007       175      23    11,22,33,12,13
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Kindly help !

Regards !

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I wrote this query just for example. I usually use INNER JOIN / OUTER JOIN in my queries. Thanks for the feedback though !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't join again the CONFIRMATION table on the subquery. You want the rows related to your main query.

```
SELECT
   C.ID_CONF,
   C.QTY,
   C.ID_LOT,
   STUFF((  
      SELECT CAST(',' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(CP.ID_PRESS AS VARCHAR(5))
      FROM CONFIRMATION_PRESS CP
      WHERE CP.ID_CONF = C.ID_CONF
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') PRESS_CSV    
FROM CONFIRMATION C 
WHERE C.ID_LOT = 175
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Silly me !! Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Begin Tran
Create Table CONFIRMATION  (ID_CONF Int,ID_LOT Int,QTY numeric)
INSert into CONFIRMATION
Select 1005,175,25 Union All
Select 1006,175,24  Union All
Select 1007,175,23 Union All
Select 1008,176,50

Create Table CONFIRMATION_PRESS (ID_CONF int ,ID_PRESS INt )
Insert into CONFIRMATION_PRESS
Select 1005,11 Union All
Select 1005,22 Union All
Select 1005,33 Union All
Select 1006,12 Union All
Select 1006,13 Union All
Select 1007,14

--Select *from CONFIRMATION Inner Join
--CONFIRMATION_PRESS On  CONFIRMATION_PRESS.ID_CONF=CONFIRMATION.ID_CONF
--Where CONFIRMATION.ID_LOT=175


SELECT
    C.ID_CONF,
    C.QTY,
    C.ID_LOT,
    STUFF((  
            SELECT  ', ' +  CONVERT(Nvarchar,CP.ID_PRESS)
            from  
            CONFIRMATION_PRESS CP

      WHERE
          C.ID_CONF = CP.ID_CONF
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') PRESS_CSV
FROM
    CONFIRMATION C 
WHERE 
    C.ID_LOT = 175

RollBack Tran
```